# How do I know a process is blocking the reboot command in linux?

Tags: linux, openwrt, reboot, busybox, imx6

I added my packages and modules into the openwrt and then `reboot` doesn't work at all!!. Only way to reboot is to use `reboot -f` or `hard reset`.

I tried removing all the `startup scripts` from `/etc/init.d` which are added by me. I even tried removing the contents of `/etc/modules.d/`.

My `/etc/rc.local` file has just one line `exit 0`.

Where should I debug to figure this out? All these package were working earlier on `x86` architecture.

Iam using `openwrt chaos calmer` on `imx6` based board.

Comment: One likely cause is a file open on media (or partition) preventing the partition from being unmounted. Do you have any shares mounted or removable media mounted when you call for reboot?  Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I did not mount anything still I see this issue

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know reboot uses the shutdown command. So when shutting down, Linux sends **SIGTERMs** to its processes. But the kernel protects the processes which are in uninterruptible state to preventing data loss. This may lead to stop the rebooting.

So in your case some processes (openwrt specific) may be in uninterruptible state. You can list out the process having uninterpreted state (**check the STAT of the process**) through `ps aux` command.

[image: Process State code]

or you can directly list the uninterruptible state by `ps -eo 'stat,pid,args' | grep -E 'D'`

check [Linux process states](https://idea.popcount.org/2012-12-11-linux-process-states/) for more details about process in linux.

Comment: I have no process with that state.